# Why does this command line restart Windows 7?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I'm writing an automated, deplorable script that uninstalls Windows 10 related updates and files from Windows 7, 8, and 8.1. However, when I run the following command line in Windows 7, It initiates a system reboot within a minute, leaving the rest of the script to be interrupted in the process.

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:******* /quiet
```

What exactly is going on? Windows 8.1 handles it fine, but Windows 7 always seems to shutdown mid-script. As a side note, the update will in fact be uninstalled once the system preps back up. When running the command without `/quiet` at the end, there is an uninstall confirmation box, and then one after that which asks to reboot now or later. Could it be that the `/quiet` command is selecting "Restart Now"? If so, how can I select "Restart Later" without having a prompt appear?

Comment: See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262841 Looks like `/norestart` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [KB93430](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/934307)7, an unattended installation (or uninstallation) will by default reboot automatically if one is needed to complete the operation.

Use the `/norestart` option to prevent that from happening.

If you do use `/norestart`, make sure you check the return value.  This will be `3010` if a restart is needed or `0` if no restart is needed; any other value indicates that the operation failed.  At the end of the script, if any of the changes returned `3010` you should reboot the machine or advise the user to do so.